# Code broke due to missing PredicateBuilder assembly after upgrade to Sitecore 7 version 130918

Tags: upgrade

During the upgrade from Sitecore 7 version 130424 to version 130918, it broke our solution.

After investigation, we found that our code is using "PredicateBuilder" class to create search queries. And found that it is missing in new Sitecore.ContentSearch.dll in this version and is throwing the error. Any help will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

We had this problem also in one of projects long time back.

Here is what we have done.

PredicateBuilder class has been moved into Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Utilities namespace(from Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities) in this version and so you need to include "Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.dll" in project and hopefully this will work.

For reference, here is the Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq assembly

[image]

Comment: I have included the reference and seems to be working. Thanks Rohit